# render specific font bigger than other fonts

Tags: css, fonts

I'm searching for a method to tell the browser to render each glyph rendered with a specific font, e.g. FreeMono, in a bigger font size than glyphs rendered with other fonts. The reason for that is, that I use characters like ᚠ in a website and these glyphs are rendered using FreeMono in Chrome (see inspect element → computed → rendered fonts) and they look always like they're to small to fit the surrounding text. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: How do define the font in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. CSS has no tools for such font-specific tuning, apart from the `font-size-adjust` property, which has very limited effect, limited browser support, and buggy support.

If you use a character such as “ᚠ” U+16A0 RUNIC LETTER FEHU FEOH FE F on a web page, then it will be up to each browser in each system which font (if any) is used to render it, at least if you do not explicitly suggest some font(s) that contain it. It may be FreeMono, but most computers in the world do not have it. Besides, in FreeMono, “ᚠ” is rather large—taller than uppercase Latin letters. So if it looks too small, the reason might be a mix of fonts.

To make, say, Runic letters match the style of other text, you should try and find a font that is suitable for both—so that you can use a single font, designer by a typographer to make things fit. You would then probably need to find a suitable free font and use it as a downloadable font (with `@font-face`). It might be FreeSerif or FreeSans; only in very peculiar circumstances would I consider FreeMono, a monospace font, suitable for rendering computer code in some cases and mostly unsuitable for everything else.